# minecraft scoreboard count multiple block Ids

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to create a Minecraft scoreboard object that counts all kinds of stone?

Like:

```
/scoreboard objectives add stonecounter stats.useItem.1
/scoreboard objectives add stonebrickcounter stats.useItem.X
/scoreboard objectives add cobblestonecounter stats.useItem.XX
```

and then sum all the objectives to one `allstonecounter` and display that number on the sideboard?

Something like:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sideboard (stonecounter+stonebrickcounter+cobblestonecounter)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use scoreboard operations to add one score to another.

```
/scoreboard players operation <affected_target> <affected_objective> <operation> <target> <objective>
```

Operations available: `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `<`, `>`, `><`, `=`

More information concerning scoreboards can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Command_reference).

**Prerequisites:**

You will need another objective to hold the value:

```
/scoreboard objectives add stonetotal dummy
```

**Clock commands:**

The following must be run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Reset all player's "stonetotal" score to 0. Without this, their score will constantly increase.

   ```
    /scoreboard players set @a[score_stonetotal_min=1] stonetotal 0
   ```
2. Cause all players to run the `/scoreboard` command, targeting their own scores. They will increment their "stonetotal" score equal to their respective stone scores.

   ```
    /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] stonetotal += @a[c=1] stonecounter
    /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] stonetotal += @a[c=1] stonebrickcounter
    /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players operation @a[c=1] stonetotal += @a[c=1] cobblestonecounter
   ```

Comment: I don't think you need to `execute` the scoreboard operation, you can use `@a stonetotal += * ...` (if memory serves).  Also, if you are going to `execute` the operation, why not use `@p` in the scoreboard portion?

Comment: @MBraedley IIRC, `@p` doesn't select dead players, whereas `@a[c=1]` can.

Comment: But, IIRC, `@a` (without the argument) doesn't select dead players either.  Or maybe I'm just thinking about a specific use of `/tp`.

Comment: @MBraedley If you don't use `/execute`, then you will be unable to change specific playerscores based on their own score. You'd instead either be changing a single player's score based on the collective scores, or changing all playerscores based on a single target's score. Using `/execute` is to split the senders up so they can increment their *own* scores based on their own scores. `@a` is the only target selector that can target dead players, so mixing `@a` with `@p` is not recommended.

Comment: See Searge's comment on [MC-46223](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-46223?focusedCommentId=138265&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-138265) ("The @a selector (but only without a radius/area defined via r/rx/ry/rz) will include dead players in the next snapshot. All other selectors work as intended.")

Comment: I guess what this really comes down to is I need to buy a couple more accounts so I can properly test multiplayer commands.

Comment: @MBraedley You can [join multiple players onto a LAN world with just one account](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148409/can-two-users-play-on-a-minecraft-server-using-the-same-account/148410#148410), or test with fake scoreboard players.