# Playing minecraft on two accounts on the same pc simultaenously

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know we can both login on two accounts on the same machine, but can we both play at the same time? If I leave one screen it goes on pause. Can I have both screens be active?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to play minecraft with multiple people on the same computer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/370770/is-it-possible-to-play-minecraft-with-multiple-people-on-the-same-computer)

Answer (score 0):

If your running two minecraft instances on one pc you can only control one instance at a time. If you enter an inventory screen ie. Player inventory or chest the game will stay running when you change to the other instance.